# I connect to the internet through 2 routers at my home, so outside my LAN how can I get into both routers?

Tags: networking, internet, router

i have one networking question, i am connected to internet using 2 routers. So my computer basically connects to one router, then that router connects to other router. I knw, user n pass of both routers. so from outside the network, how can i get into the 2nd router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to forward the inner router's external admin port (configurable in its settings) to the inner router using the outer router's settings panel.

Make sure to enable SSL in the remote admin settings.

Depending on your network topology and on what you want to do with it, you may want to place the inner router in the outer router's DMZ.  (and be sure to setup the inner router's firewall correctly)

Comment: You need to forward the "inner router's" external admin port (configurable in its settings) to the "inner router" using the outer router's settings panel.

Comment: @oDx: Yes; that's exactly what I said.  What?